# ¿Cómo cierro la sesion en Stack Overflow?

Tags: soporte, interfaz-de-usuario

No encuentro la opción para cerrar la sesión, hasta ahora solo borro las ["cookies"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

Comment: en la esquina superior derecha, de los 5 íconos disponibles el último en el borde que es como un globo de diálogo dividido en 3, das clic en el él y en la opción que dice **salir**

Comment: No se como no lo vi antes, apreté ese botón muchas veces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Entorno web desde escritorio**

---

Desde escritorio en tu navegador del lado superior derecho, busca el siguiente ícono que parece un globo de diálogo dividido en 3 secciones

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez hecho lo anterior, tendrás las siguientes 3 opciones a tu alcance, además como puedes observar te indica en que comunidad de la red de *Stack Exchange* te encuentras actualmente.

Solo basta con dar clic en la opción de la orilla derecha que dice **Salir** para que logres terminar tu sesión

1. Ayuda
2. Chat
3. Salir

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]